# chrome os kiosk load content from usb

Tags: usb, kiosk, google-chrome-os

I am new to Chrome OS and have written a NFC enabled kiosk app and installed it on my managed Chromebit so that it enters kiosk mode on boot.
This is working well.

I would now like to have the kiosk app load html files from an external usb device rather than the cloud due to large files, video etc. something like 
webview src=files://USB Drive/Video1/index.html is what I have in mind.

I have read up on the fileSystem API and that it is supported for kiosk apps running in kiosk mode, which my app is, but I cannot get it to work.

The below code results in the error shown.

chrome.fileSystem.getVolumeList( function(volumes){

```
if (volumes === undefined)
{
    log("Error: " + JSON.stringify(chrome.runtime.lastError));
}
else
{
    $.each(volumes, function(i, v){
        log("Volume: " + v.volumeid + ", Writable: " + v.writable);
    });

    // Request Filesystem
    log("Requesting filesystem...");
    chrome.fileSystem.requestFileSystem(volumes[0].volumeid, function(fs) {

        if (fs === undefined)
        {
            log("Error: " + JSON.stringify(chrome.runtime.lastError));
        }
        else
        {
            log(JSON.stringify(fs));
        }
    });
}
```

});

and the error:

Error: {"message":"Operation only supported for kiosk apps running in a kiosk session."}

My app is a kiosk app running in a kiosk session!

My manifest is as follows:

{
  "name": "****",

"version": "0.1",

"description": "****",

"manifest_version": 2,

"icons": {

```
  "128": "icon_128.png",

  "16": "icon_16.png"

},
```

"permissions": [

```
"usb",

{

  "usbDevices": [

    { "vendorId": 1839, "productId": 8704 } // This is the NFC USB reader

  ]

},

"webview",

"audio",

"enterprise.deviceAttributes",

"power",

"unlimitedStorage",

{"fileSystem": ["write", "retainEntries", "directory", "requestFileSystem"] }
```

],

"app": {

```
"background": {

  "scripts": [ "background.js" ]

}
```

},

"kiosk_enabled": true

}

Any help on getting my kiosk app to load html content from an external USB would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add "kiosk_only": true in the manifest file.

Comment: Thank you this indeed was what was required. If I try and access the file on the USB via the webview I am seeing this error in my logs: webview loadabort: url file:///media/removable/USB Drive/index.html   ERR_DISALLOWED_URL_SCHEME are you able to assist  on how to permit the file:// scheme?

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible. file:// scheme is not allowed for webviews, at least on Chrome OS. What do you try to achieve? There may be another, easier way.

Comment: We need to play 4K video on the display hence do not want to drag it across the LAN or WAN. A simple file://media/.... to reference the local USB file store would be ideal. The user can then simply plug in an updated USB stick in to update content.

Comment: You can do it with this API. Try videoTag.src = URL.createObjectURL(entry.file()).

Comment: Thanks I will try that and update here. I take it that the entry.file is from a file reader object and that should have permissions to the USB drive as requested in the manifest?

Comment: No no no. You said that you're using chrome.fileSystem.requestFileSystem API, so after obtaining a file system you can obtain an entry. Please check the examples here: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Comment: I see. Thank you, I now have it working. I really appreciate your effort!

Comment: As an additional note. It appears that if the URL contains arguments another step is needed as the content will not load. Not sure at this stage what is required. Example URL index.html?video=foo.mp4 I have tried appending the query string after the URL.createObjectURL(entry.file()) result but this does not work. If the entry.file() is the actual video file eg. video.mp4 then it works. If the entry.file() is html page containing a video tag, it does not work.

Comment: That's right. It won't work, as in packaged apps you can only open files which are bundled in the packaged app *or* opened via File System API *or* remote (http/https) files if allowed in the packaged app manifest file. That foo.mp4 doesn't meet any of these criteria. I'd recommend you to directly open video files (entry.file() pointing to the video file) and move the html code to the packaged app.

Comment: Unfortunately that would mean that you can't set the standard <video> tag elements like loop etc. if the file is on the USB drive. Is there a way to copy all files from the USB to the Kiosks app local storage using the File System API and then play from there? That way we could detected the USB, copy the files and then all content is relative to the Apps storage path.

Comment: You still can set standard attributes on <video>. You do the same html file, just put it in the packaged app. Then open it eg. via chrome.app.window.create("player.html", ..."). player.html would contain <video> tag and a JS script which would load the file from USB drive and then set attributes including src on the <video> tag.

No need to copy files. Could you provide more details?

Comment: OK so if I include a playvideo.html file packaged with the app I will need to pass a URL param with what video I want it to play. This video is on the USB drive so do I need to first use objURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file); to create the path and then supply this to the webview src? E.g webview src=local_app_content/playvideo.html?video=<objURL goes here>

Comment: Not sure if you can use webview this way. You should use chrome.app.window.create("local_app_content/playvideo.html?video=<objURL goes here>") or something like that. You can try both.

Comment: OK I will try and then update my findings. If using window.create this will cause issues as we will need to close the window once the video is complete. ChromeOS making this simple task very hard!

Comment: Newbie, why hard? It's very easy. You need some window anyway to show contents to user. In your kiosk app you must already have a window. You don't need to create a new one, you can just have a <video> element in it and change source to window.URL.createObjectURL(file) in JavaScript.